# Regular expression works on Linux but not on Solaris

Tags: c++, regex, linux, solaris

i wrote a C++ program which parses log files that are written too fast as that anyone could read it.
The program should find every line with the a word like 'WARN' but not the word 'WARNA'.
as i said it works fine on Linux but not on Solaris.
i used `regcomp()` with the `REG_EXTENDED` flag.

`regcomp()` doesn't throw an error and `regexec` returns 1 `(REG_NOMATCH)`.

I use `regexec()` and `regcomp()`.

I have this really long regular expression it works fine in Linux

```
.*([^A-Za-z1-9]|\s)(error|ERROR|Error|fatal|FATAL|Fatal|excep|EXCEP|Excep|warn|WARN|Warn|problem|PROBLEM|Problem|fail|FAIL|Fail|fault|Fault|FAULT|cannot|Cannot|CanNot|CANNOT|cannot|Cannot|CANNOT|cant|can't|Cant|Can't|unable|Unable|UNABLE|mandatory|Mandatory|MANDATORY|mustnot|Mustnot|MustNot|MUSTNOT|couldnot|Couldnot|CouldNot|COULDNOT|didnot|Didnot|DidNot|DIDNOT|violat|Violat|VIOLAT|damage|Damage|DAMAGE|missing|Missing|notfinish|mandatory|Mandatory|MANDATORY|broken|Broken|BROKEN)([^a-zA-Z1-9]).*
```

Comment: Why not to use `boost::regex`?

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what version?

Comment: There must be a way to check for "error" without case so you don't need `error|ERROR|Error`.

Comment: Show us the lines it is failing on for Solaris but working for Linux

Comment: I am using the "g++ (GCC) 3.4.3 (csl-sol210-3_4-branch+sol_rpath)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc."

Comment: @minzchickenflavor That compiler is over 10 years old which might explain the difference in behaviour with the presumably newer compiler you are using on Linux.

Comment: the library in which the recomp and regexec functions are is already compiled. So the functions are just linked in by the linker and i don't guess that the linker does a failure that would have different results. Tell me if i am wrong. But the old compiler generates the same assembler lines as the new  (at least when they call the function regexec)

Comment: @minzchickenflavor, since your Solaris can be quite outdated, you can factor out incompatible versions of regexec etc and use the same code base for your regular expressions.  Either boost::regex, if it is supported by your platform, or pcre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.
The problem was that linux doesn't need the `^`at the beginning of the regex string or the `$` at the end of the string.
But for the Solaris function it seems to be necessary.